# Invoking named routes helpers in views ends with NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Invoking named routes helpers in views ends with NameError for following configuration:

`routes.rb`:

```
scope :orders, as: :orders do
  scope '/:order_id', as: :order do
    post :returns, :to => 'order_returns#create'
  end
end
```

`$rake routes`:

```
orders_order_returns POST /orders/:order_id/returns(.:format) order_returns#create
```

When I add `<%= orders_order_returns_path %>` to template, `Rails`exit with `undefined local variable or method 'orders_order_returns_path' for #<#<Class:0x007faec10fe728>:0x007faec10dc8d0>`...

Executing `Rails.application.routes.named_routes.helpers.map(&:to_s)` in console on exception page returns:

```
["spree_path", "orders_order_returns_path", "rails_info_properties_path", "rails_info_routes_path", "rails_info_path", "rails_mailers_path", "spree_url", "orders_order_returns_url", "rails_info_properties_url", "rails_info_routes_url", "rails_info_url", "rails_mailers_url"]
```

My question is: why using named routes path/url helpers in view ends with exception even when they are visible in consoles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer [here](http://osdir.com/ml/spree-user/2012-02/msg00043.html):

> Because you're calling this inside a spree template you need to prefix it with `main_app.`, like `main_app.products_starting_with_path`

Here's release note from Spree:

> Conversely, to reference routes from the main application within a
>   controller, view or template from Spree, you must use the `main_app`
>   routing proxy

Using `main_app` routing proxy solved described problem :)